# Double pointer doesn't call object constructor when using new

Tags: c++

My problem seems to be answered with only single pointers. I'm trying to dynamically allocate for a 2d linked list. The problem I ran into when I'm trying to use class llist constructor to set head and tail pointer to NULL :

```
//I've included only the parts that I see are neccesary
 struct node {
    int value ;
    int weight ;
    node* next ;
 } ;
 class  llist{
      private :
          node* tail, *head ;
      public :
           llist(){tail = NULL ;  head = NULL ;} /* this unneccesary retype is to make sure 
                                                    that it wasn't a typo*/
}
class list_graph
{
    private :
        int size, s;
        llist ** v ;
    public :
        list_graph(int s){
             this -> s = s ;
             size = 0 ;
        v = new llist* [s] ; 
        }
}
```

I've use the debugger and ran through every steps and it seems that my constructor for `llist` is not called after I create a object of `list_graph` type, so every other function that relies on this fails and gives me segmentation  fault. Is there anything I'm doing wrong, or is there any workarounds beside using the STL list, many thanks

Comment: Why should the `llist` constructor be called? You're not creating any `llist` objects, instead you're creating `llist*` objects.

Comment: `v = new llist* [s]` dynamically allocates an array of pointers.  A pointer of type `llist *` is a different thing from a `llist`.   If you want the constructor of `llist` to be called, you need to construct one or more `llist`s, not pointers to them,

Comment: Seems you are trying to create a 2d array of linked lists? It's not entirely clear. But in any case the procedure for creating a 2d array is the same whether it's a 2d array of linked lists or a 2d array of integers, Suggest you google how to allocate a 2d array.

Comment: I've explained that I'm trying to create a 2d linked list. And Google wasn't of help since I'm trying to call the constructor

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what a 2d linked list is, or how it relates to your code. Do you mean a 1d array of linked lists?

Comment: I don't know the exact term for it, but basically I'm trying to create pointer to a bunch of other pointers of linked list so it    ressemble a 2d array

Comment: @TraiViệtNam I suspect you have got too many pointers, and Neil's answer is the correct one. Your `llist` object already has pointers internally, and you're add two more levels of pointers in `list_graph`. That's **three** levels of pointers. Change `list_graph` to be `llist * v` and your constructor will be called

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please ?

Comment: @TraiViệtNam Elaborate on what exactly? Stop thinking about pointers. If you want an array of linked lists and you don't want to use `std::vector` or `std::list` then `llist * v` and `v = new llist [s];` is the correct code.

Comment: @john oh it just snapped in my head, wonder what I was thinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
  v = new llist* [s] ;
```

creates an array of pointers to type `llist`, but it doesn't create any `llist` objects. If you want an array of such things, then you want:

```
  llist * v ;
```

and:

```
  v = new llist[s] ;
```

Or better still, if this is not a homework assignment, use std::vector. And don't think of things like `llist ** v` as "double pointers"; think of them as what they are - pointers to pointers.

Comment: Well that's the problem, I'm trying to avoid vectors, so I ran into this

Comment: This kinda defeats my purpose of creating a 2d linked list though

Comment: Why do you want to create one? What are you going to use it for?

Comment: I'm using it for my graph class file, I want to be able to specify the size so this happens

Comment: Why can't you do that with std::list or std::vector?

Comment: I'm trying to do everything myself so I can grasp what's going on instead of just slamming stl everywhere

Comment: @TraiViệtNam -- *I'm trying to do everything myself* -- Note you haven't mentioned how you're going to clean up all the memory you've allocated.

Comment: As  you  can see I'm not  that proficient yet, so I'm going to assume the answer you're hoping for is delete lol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate a 2D pointer array, you can do it a couple ways:

Using a dynamic array of pointer arrays, given some `width` and `height`:

```
llist** data = new llist*[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i){
    data[i] = new llist[height]; // constructors get called here
}

// accessing a linked list, make sure x is in [0, width) and y is in [0, height):
data[x][y]->value;
```

Using a single pointer array:

```
llist* data = new llist[width * height]; // constructors get called here

// accessing a linked list:
// again, make sure x is in [0, width) and y is in [0, height)
data[x + (y * width)]->value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `v` as a array of pointers to `llist` objects, as opposed to an array of `llist` objects (suggested by Neil Butterworth), dynamically allocate each pointer by changing your `list_graph` constructor to

```
  list_graph(int s) : size(0), s(s), v(new llist* [s]) {
    for (int i(0); i < s; ++i)
      v[i] = new llist();
  }
```

EDIT: To avoid calling `new` `s` times in the for loop, you could pre-allocate all `s` `llist` objects at once. However, this would mean they can not be deleted individually. Your class would look like

```
class list_graph {
  int size, s;
  llist* buffer;
  llist ** v ;
public:
  list_graph(int s) : size(0), s(s),
      buffer(new llist[s]), v(new llist* [s]) {
    for (int i(0); i < s; ++i)
      v[i] = &buffer[i];
  }
  ~list_graph() {
    delete[] v;
    delete[] buffer;
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this that doesn't involve a loop ? It's going to cost me my precious runtime

Comment: @Trai: You could initialize them all at once in a contiguous array, but that means you can't delete them individually. Is this OK?

Comment: No but I've found my bugs, thanks for the help  anyways